# Error al instalar taildwind css - ' taildwindcss@latest is not in npm registry '

Tags: npm, tailwind, vite

Hola acabo de empezar un proyecto personal con react usando **vite** con el comando `npm create vite@latest`, y todo ha ido bien, pero cuando he querido instalar taildwind css me pasa esto:

Hice el siguiente comando `npm install -D taildwindcss postcss autoprefixer` siguiendo la documentación oficial de inicio de tailwindcss https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Y la consola me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a omitir la -D del comando por si tenía algo que ver, no es el caso, me pasa igual.

No es la primera vez que uso taildwind, siempre he iniciado mis proyectos de la misma manera, este error es la primera vez que me ocurre, así que no sé ciertamente que está pasando.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

intentalo de esta manera:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

o intenta con una version previa:

3.1.7

Comment: Hola que tal, sí estuve viendo esa solución aquí https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn/issues/65 (mismo error aparentemente), y funciona, instala los paquetes bien, pero no termino de entender por qué no funciona de la otra forma cuando hasta ahora no tenía ese problema. ¿Quizás es algo puntual de tailwind que tienen que corregir los desarrolladores?

Comment: @JuanJesús as intentado con la version previa 3.1.7?

Comment: Me instaló la última que es la 3.1.8, si quisiera instalar la 3.1.7 sería poniendo npm i tailwindcss@3.1.7 ? Mi versión de node es la v14.16.0 no creo que tenga algo que ver. En cualquier caso, he podido resolver el problema, si más adelante ocurre igual pues usaré el comando con @latest